# A solid sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$ is cut into two parts by a plane $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, volume

A solid sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$ is cut into two parts by a plane $z=\frac{1}{2}$. Find the volume of the smaller part.
I have no idea how to approach this.
It will be helpful if you give me the general way to approach these problems.

Comment: You may want to look at this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Comment: If you are looking for a general approach by triple integrals you can use cylindrical or spherical coordinates. Otherwise we can use simplear approaches based on the formulas for the volume of solid of revolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

By [**cylindrical coordinates**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html) we have

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{\frac12}^1 dz\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}r\,dr=\pi\int_{\frac12}^1 (1-z^2)dz$$

As an alternative we could also use spherical coordinates but I think that cylindrical coordinates are more effective to use here.

If you are not forced to use triple integral, as noticed by B. Goddard, you may refer to the formula for [**Volumes of Solids of Revolution**](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx) that is

$$\int_a^b \pi (f(z))^2 dz$$

obtaing of course the same result.

Comment: thanks! this helped a lot

Comment: @LegendKiller That's nice! You are welcome, Bye

Answer (score 1):

This is a Calc I problem.  Rotate the region under the curve $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ from $x=1/2$ to $1$ about the $x$-axis.

$$\int_{1/2}^1 \pi \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2 \; dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Volume of the smaller part (a spherical cup) $$V=\frac{\pi h^2}{3}(3r-h)$$
Note that here $r=1$ and $h=r-(1/2)=1/2$

Comment: That's could be useful to check it but I think that the OP is looking for a method to derive it.

Comment: Yes this is just a special case but as OP was struggling to find any approach this might be a place to start thinking.

Comment: Sorry but I think that a given formula does not help to start. It could be solely useful for a check, I suggest to present your answer in that perspective.